# Update parent table from child in Asp.net and fluent nhibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net, fluent-nhibernate, unitofworkapplication

I'm trying to update the data in the parent table that is referenced in the child table from the child's view in Asp.net.

I mapped the tables using Fluent Nhibernate.

In the child table, the mapping looks like this:

```
public class ChildMap: ClassMap<Child>
{
    public ChildMap()
    {
        Id(i => i.childID).Not.Nullable();
        Map(i => i.childValue1);
        Map(i => i.childValue2);
        Map(i => i.childValue3);
        References(i => i.parent, "parentID").Cascade.All();
    }
```

The parent table's mapping:

```
public class ParentMap: ClassMap<Parent>
{
    public ParentMap()
    {
        Id(i => i.parentID).Not.Nullable();
        Map(i => i.parentValue1);
        Map(i => i.parentValue2);
        Map(i => i.parentValue3);
        HasMany(i => i.Child).KeyColumn("childID").Cascade.All().Inverse();

    }
}
```

In my controller, it looks like this...

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {

        try
        {
            using (var tr = UnitOfWork.CurrentUnitOfWork.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {

                    var child= Registry.Childs.Get(id);

                    //This update works
                    UpdateModel(child, new[] { "childValue1", "childValue2", "childValue3" }, collection.ToValueProvider());

                    //This update on the parent doesn't work
                    UpdateModel(child.parent, new[] { "child.parent.parentValue1", "child.parent.parentValue2", "child.parent.parentValue3" }, collection.ToValueProvider());

                    tr.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    tr.Rollback();
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

With the codes above, when I try to update the values in the child table, it works. However, if I try to save the changes in the parent table, it doesn't work.

Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. I just answered my own question. Basically just add the table name of the parent for it to work.

```
UpdateModel(child.parent, "Parent", new[] { "child.parent.parentValue1", "child.parent.parentValue2", "child.parent.parentValue3" }, collection.ToValueProvider());
```

Yay!!!